# set up proper date format

Tags: date-format, sql-loader, to-date, ctl

in csv file I have column, where are date's with diffrent format as below:

02/03/2014 00:10
1/02/2014 7:25:00
7/03/2013 8:30:00 PM

How to set up proper date into CTL file in SQL-LOADER?
    `column1 "to_date(:column1, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')"`

Comment: Did you try anything so far? If you did, what error you're getting?

Comment: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Comment: Does your data file contains date in varying format as shown above?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is, have one format in your data. You cannot have date in multiple formats and then parse that using your CTL file.